# Error while running typescript node using geo-tz in build file

Tags: node.js, typescript, geolocation

I am using **geo-tz** in our Typescript Nodejs application for getting the geolocation details. When i am running the node server locally, it's working fine but when taken a node server build , i am getting an error like the below while calling geo-tz function like this:

```
import * as  geoTz from 'geo-tz';
const testGeotz= ()=>{
       try{
           const coords = [-122.350070,47.650499]
            let name = geoTz(coords[1], coords[0])[0];
           }catch (e) {
               console.log(e);
           }
}
```

[image]

Why is it happening like this ?
My node version - 12.16.3
geo-tz version - 6.0.0

I even tried downgrading the geo-tz version and tried to upgrade to latest v6.0.1 .Still same response.
Please tell me whether I have missed out any dependency .